# python selenium firefox - add_extension not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Trying to add uBlock to a browser session but it's not working.

```
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as options


def establish_browser(type, hide):
    browser = ''
    if type == 'firefox':
        ops = options()
        ops.add_argument("--headless") if hide is True else ops.add_argument("--head")
        profile = selenium.webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        profile.add_extension(extension='uBlock0@raymondhill.net.xpi')
        browser = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path='geckodriver.exe', options=ops, firefox_binary=FirefoxBinary('C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'))
    return browser

browser = establish_browser('firefox', False)
```

How should this be changed so uBlock works?

***UPDATE***

The chrome version appears to be working …

```
if type == 'chrome':
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as options
    ops = options()
    ops.add_argument("--headless") if hide is True else ops.add_argument("--head")
    ops.add_extension("ublock.crx")
    browser = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', options=ops, desired_capabilities={'binary_location': 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'})
```

is Firefox depreciated?

Comment: Did you create an issue about this on geckodriver issue tracker ?

Comment: I might do that actually, I'll look into it tomorrow

Answer (score 3):

Since, for some reason, chrome's `add_extension` works but firefox's `add_extension` does not work (currently)  … here is my workaround for adding extensions to firefox.

1. create a new firefox profile via `right click windows start button > run > firefox.exe -P`
2. Then add whatever extensions you want, ublock, adblock plus etc
3. call your profile folder with

`profile = selenium.webdriver.FirefoxProfile("C:/test")`

`browser = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=ops)`

Apparently `profile.add_extension()` is not a must have for this workaround

**UPDATE! - added chrome profile**

For symmetry purposes I have updated the chrome example code to use the chrome profile instead of calling the `.crx` directly.

1. install extensions onto chrome's default profile.
2. navigate to `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome` or where-ever chromes `User Data` folder is located. Call this folder directly (absolute path) or rename it and call the relative path. I have renamed it to `chrome_profile`:

   ```
   ops = options()
   ops.add_argument("--headless") if hide is True else ops.add_argument("--head")
   ops.add_argument('user-data-dir=chrome_profile')
   ops.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
   ops.add_argument("--incognito")
   browser = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', options=ops, desired_capabilities={'binary_location': 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'})
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Rhys' solution, an easier approach might be the following option from the [official documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver) which works as expected:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox('path/to/executable')
driver.install_addon('~/path/to/addon.xpi')
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31250686)

Comment: Agreed, that's why the necessary code is included below.