# Selenium Firefox profile.add_extension not working. Script running fine but I don't see any extension

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, firefox-addon

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxProfile

driver = webdriver.Firefox(
  executable_path=r'C:\Users\subha\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.30.0-win64\geckodriver.exe')


profile = FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Users\subha\AppData\Roaming\\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\e7j8p01g.F1')
profile.add_extension(r'C:\Users\subha\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\e7j8p01g.F1\extensions\CanvasBlocker@kkapsner.de.xpi')



driver.get('https://github.com')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible duplicate from [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844832/python-selenium-firefox-add-extension-not-working). A more elegant solution than the workaround proposed there is the following option from the [official documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver) which works as expected:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox('path/to/executable')
driver.install_addon('~/path/to/addon.xpi')
```

In your case do:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\subha\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.30.0-win64\geckodriver.exe')
driver.install_addon(r'C:\Users\subha\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\e7j8p01g.F1\extensions\CanvasBlocker@kkapsner.de.xpi')
#Maybe time.sleep() a few seconds to give time for the installation, then

driver.get('https://github.com')
```

Comment: `driver.install_addon` worked perfectly! This answer should appear higher up in Google's search results.