# Python and Selenium: Locating and clicking a button for cookies within an iframe

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

Anybody has a solution to locate a button in webpage with an overlayed popup window like in the following example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'./geckodriver')
driver.get("https://www.academics.de/")
#after waiting for a while the popup window comes up
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Zustimmen')]")
```

The returned list is empty. Running the following

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".button-accept")
```

results in:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .button-accept
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element with the text as *E-Mail Login* is within an [*iframe*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.academics.de/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='SP Consent Message']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='Zustimmen']"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.academics.de/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='SP Consent Message']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@title='Zustimmen']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Answer (score 0):

An easy workaround to your problem would be to use [uBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/) extension + [Fanboy's Annoyances](https://secure.fanboy.co.nz/fanboy-annoyance.txt) blocklist on your Selenium instance so that these annoying cookies messages would outright never appear. A way of enabling extensions is described in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53859263/11010254):

> 1. Create a new firefox profile via right click windows start button >
>    run > firefox.exe -P
> 2. Then add whatever extensions you want, ublock, adblock plus etc
> 3. Call your profile folder with

> `profile = selenium.webdriver.FirefoxProfile("C:/test")`

> `browser = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=ops)`